# partial_fit with scikit-learn returns ValueError: The sum of the priors should be 1

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sum, naivebayes

I am trying to run a `sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB` model with `partial_fit`. For this I calculate the `priors` like this:

```
unique_lbls, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
counts = counts.astype(float)
priors = counts / counts.sum()
model  = GaussianNB(priors=priors)
model.partial_fit(X, y, classes=unique_lbls)
```

I get an `ValueError: The sum of the priors should be 1, but I have checked and the priors do sum up to 1.0:

```
print priors.sum()
> 1.0
```

I am using the following versions:

```
Python 2.7.12
scikit-learn 0.18.2
numpy 1.13.1
```

I can only imagine that it comes down to sensitivity of the summed value, but I have tried to normalize the priors again with `priors /= priors.sum()` and it returns the same error.

Is there a different way to make sure that the priors sum to 1.0 with a higher tolerance, or is there some (to me not-)obvious reason this doesn't work?

Edit: `labels` is a numpy array with containing the whole data set's labels represented as integers, X and y are a batch of the full data set. 
`y` and `labels` both have at least 100 examples from each class.

Comment: Not helpful at all, but it works fine for me on Python 2.7.10, sklearn 0.18.2 and numpy 1.13.1. It's unlikely a Python thing, but could be. Can you post some data to see if I can recreate with your data?

Comment: Do you have values in `y` that are not in `unique_lbls`? (as per documentation of [`partial_fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.partial_fit))

Comment: It was complicated creating an example of data, so I instead tried reproducing the error by using a set of random values created as `X = numpy.random.rand(10000,100)` and `y = numpy.random.int(10000)`. I follow the same steps as above and this works without any issue. So there must be something with my data. The question remains though how `priors.sum()` can return `1.0` and partial_fit still complains about it not being the case. 
@kazemakase All classes in `y` are found in `unique_lbls`

Comment: I no longer think it's the data. I strongly suspect that if you do `priors.sum() == 1.0` you will get `False`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

My first intuition was that something is wrong with the data. However, it looks like the `partial_fit` function does not even look at the data before raising that error. In particular, [the implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L366) looks like this:

```
# Check that the sum is 1
if priors.sum() != 1.0:
    raise ValueError('The sum of the priors should be 1.')
```

They compare the sum of the priors exactly to 1.0, which is numerically not very robust. If you have an unlucky combination of values the normalized priors may not sum precisiely to `1.0`. Consider this:

```
priors = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=float)
priors /= priors.sum()
print(priors.sum() == 1.0)  # False
```

Such a situation will make the check fail. Let's try to fix this:

```
priors[0] = 1.0 - priors[1:].sum()
print(priors.sum() == 1.0)  # True
```

Comment: A very curious problem. I tried implementing your solution, but it failed as well. I actually tried your exact example above, and it also fails at the end. Could it be something arising only in certain versions of scikit-learn or numpy?

Comment: Could be... I'm pretty much of ideas, sorry.

Comment: For testing may I ask which version of python, scikit-learn and python you are using? Maybe I can figure it out that way.

Comment: Oh, instead of using `err` you could also try `priors[0] = 1 - priors[1:].sum()`